# Is it possible to change the Url which JQuery's JQueryUI Autocomplete generates?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

I'm using JQuery JQueryUI's AutoComplete code. It goes to my url i provide (to find the answers), but appends `?term=<search query>` after the url.

I'm trying to get the following url intead ...

`/myurl/<term / search query>`

eg.

```
/myurl/abcd
/myurl/hello+world
```

etc...

is it possible to do this?

Otherwise, it is possible to rename the query parameter `term` to something else, .. like `query` to `q`, etc?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) yourself in the [`source` option](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source), for example:

```
$(".autocomplete").autocomplete({ 
  source: function(req, resp) {
    $.getJSON("/myurl/" + encodeURIComponent(req.term), resp);
  }
});
```

[Something similar happens](http://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js#L224) when you give it a string, it sends the first parameter passed to the method as the object...which has a property `term`, by doing it manually you're just getting more control over your parameters. I'm also using [`encodeURIComponent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference:Global_Functions:encodeURIComponent) above to be safe when generating a url directly (e.g. spaces to `+`, etc.).

Comment: saves the day again. Cheers mate :) Much appreciated.