# Not sure how to use the JQuery UI Autocomplete ... :(

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

this is a continuation from a [previous JQueryUI Autocomplete question, I asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694551/is-it-possible-to-change-the-url-which-jquerys-jqueryui-autocomplete-generates).

This time, I have my data returning ... but I have no idea *how* i define what html to show and how to dynamically update that html with my results.

So, here's my jquery ....

`Home.js`

```
function AutoComplete(element) {
    var cache = {};
    $(element).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            if (request.term in cache) {
                response(cache[request.term]);
                return;
            }
            else {
                $.getJSON("/api/autocomplete/" + 
                            encodeURIComponent(request.term),
                    function (data) {
                        cache[request.term] = data;
                        response(data);
                    });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and this is wired up in my View

`Index.aspx`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        AutoComplete("#searchQuestion");
    })
</script>
```

Now .. i'm not sure how i tell it to use some (yet to be made) html/div/etc. ... and then to populate that `<ul>` list (i'm assuming i extend the callback, above .. instead of calling this `response(data)` method .. wtf is that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's my working example of jQuery UI's autocomplete. Hope it helps:

```
    var cache = {};
    $("#textbox").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
       if (request.term in cache) {
        response($.map(cache[request.term].d, function(item) {
         return { value: item.value, id: item.id }
        }))
        return;
       }
       $.ajax({
        url: "/Services/AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetEmployees",  /* I use a web service */
        data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "' }",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
        success: function(data) {
         cache[request.term] = data;
         response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
          return {
           value: item.value,
           id: item.id
          }
         }))
        },
        error: HandleAjaxError  // custom method
       });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function(event, ui) {
       if (ui.item) {
        formatAutoComplete(ui.item);   // custom method
       }
      }
     });
```

If you're not doing so by now, get **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)**. It's an invaluable tool for web development. You can set a breakpoint on this JavaScript and see what happens.

Comment: @Rafael Belliard : cheers for the answer. Yep, been using Firebug for eons. Now .. what's $.map(..) ??? does the autocomplete use some magic html it creates on the fly, hidden away from you and I .. but requires a value + id ? Also, what's the formatAutoComplete(..) method? what's that suppose to do?

Comment: @Pure.Krome: $map is just a fancy method for iterating through arrays: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/

Comment: @Pure.Krome: formatAutocomplete() is not necessary for a simple setup. I wired it up because while the autocomplete textbox shows the item.Value, I want another textbox to show the item.Key, so it only does a $("othertextbox").val(item.Id); The (if(ui.item)) is just to check the item is not null so it doesn't crash.

Comment: @Pure.Krome: from what I just observed with Firebug, it indeed creates 'magic HTML', where each autocomplete element is formatted with <li class="ui-menu-item" role="menuitem"><a>Data shown</a></li>

Comment: ok. gotcha. i had to do the following ... `function (data) {
                        var results = $.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                               value: item.Question,
                               id: item.UniqueQuestion
                            }
                        });  and this now works :)

                        cache[request.term] = results;
                        response(results);
                    });`

Answer (score 0):

This code worked for me:

```
$( "#Textbox" ).autocomplete({
    minLength: 2,
    source: function( request, response ) {
            var term = request.term;
            if ( term in cache ) {
                response( cache[ term ] );
                return;
            }

            var currentProject=$("#project option:selected").text();
            $.ajax({
                    url:  "url",
                    data: {term : request.term, IssueType :'Test', Project : currentProject},
                    dataType: "json",     
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
                    success: function (data) {
                        var results = $.map(data, function(item){
                            return { value: item.value, id: item.id }}); 
                            cache[request.term] = results; response(results); }
            });
    }
});
```