# jQuery AutoComplete does not show up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-2, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Inside a jquery dialog I would like to use the jquery autocomplete feature of jqueryUI.

I have then prepared an action in my Controller (I am using ASP.NET MVC2) that is as follow

```
public ActionResult GetForos(string startsWith, int pageSize)
{
    // get records from underlying store
    int totalCount = 0;
    string whereClause = "Foro Like '" + startsWith + "%'";
    List<Foro> allForos = _svc.GetPaged(whereClause, "Foro", 0, pageSize, out totalCount);

    //transform records in form of Json data
    List<ForoModelWS> foros = new List<ForoModelWS>();
    foreach ( Foro f in allForos)
        foros.Add( new ForoModelWS() { id= Convert.ToString(f.ForoId), 
            text= f.Foro + ", Sezione: " + f.Sezione + ", " + f.AuthorityIdSource.Name });

    return Json(foros);
}
```

The class ForoModelWS is a simple class used only to hold the data that shall be transferred in json. Here it is

```
public class ForoModelWS
{
    public string id;
    public string text;
}
```

On the client side I have the following jquery code:

```
<input id="theForo" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#theForo").autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "/Foro/GetForos",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        startsWith: request.term,
                        pageSize: 15
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        response($.map(data, function(item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.text,
                                value: item.text
                            }
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
            },
            open: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function() {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

But the sliding window with the suggeestions does not appear. If I put an alert inside the response function I can see the correct data.

Do I miss something?

Thanks for helping

**1st EDIT**:
Moreover, How to change the code to use the "id" property of the selected element in the returned list?

**2nd EDIT**:
I have checked more with Chrome developer tool and I have seen that when autocomplete starts some error appear. the following:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'zIndex' of undefined  @ _assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js:317
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined @ _assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js:321
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined @ _assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.4.custom.min.js:320
```

It seems that the autocomplete plugin does not find an element when it tries to set the z-Index of the sliding suggestion 1 level up its container. The first error appear when the jquery UI Dialog opens. The input for the autocomplete is inside a jquery tab that is inside a jquery Dialog

**3rd EDIT**:
I am adding the HTML markup to be complete

```
<td width="40%">
   <%= Html.LabelFor(model => model.ForoID)%>
   <br />
   <%= Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ForoID) %>
   <input id="theForo" />
   <%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ForoID, "*")%>
</td>
```

Comment: The problem might be related with the fact that you're using it within the dialog. What happens if you use the autocomplete outside of the dialog? (trying to discard things).

Comment: Seems to look ok to me. Is there an javascript error at all? Is it your css hiding it or something like that?

Comment: @Claudio and Charlino: Please have a look to the question edit

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the problem.

In my case I was using also another plugin, [this one](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/).

That plugin was included at the end of my scripts and caused the error described in the question. I have removed the plugin and everything work very fine.

Before removing it I have tried also to isolate the problem putting in a static html both the scripts. I experienced that even the simplest usage of the autocomplete features, like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++", "Clojure",
    "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell", "Java", "JavaScript",
    "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

    $("#theForo").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
});
</script>
```

would cause the error I got.

My choice has been to remove the menu plugin even because that code is'nt supported anymore.

Thanks!

Comment: The fg.menu and autocomplete both add .menu() to jQuery.  I renamed the fg.menu to $.fn.fgmenu and they cooperate now.

Comment: can you share your code please? or at least give more info on the changes to do... :) thanks!

Comment: Anyway, that menu does not permit me to attach jquery events at runtime to the <a> element (the menuitem). really nice but really bad!

Comment: It's a quick change in the fg.menu.js.  Change the line that reads " $.fn.menu = function(options) { " to " $.fn.fgmenu = function(options) { ".  And then to use the menu you call $().fgmenu().

Comment: Hey @CoreyDownie your comment solved my problem Today. I goggled and read your comment and problem gone. Thank you. :)

Comment: Spent a good chunk of my day trying to figure this out... Would never have guessed this was the cause.

Answer (score 5):

This discussion is really old however adding it here just in case it helps someone...If the autocomplete is not working at all as in the drop down does not show up then first check for  the most simple form of it with hard coded suggestions like below.

```
$("#txtLanguage").autocomplete({ source: ["c++", "java", "php", "coldfusion", "javascript", "asp", "ruby"] });
```

If this does not work then it IS a problem of jquery scripts linked. In my case jquery.min.js was an older version 1.7.1 whereas all other scripts were 1.8.18.

Simply replacing the correct version of script solved the problem.

Hope this helps someone stumbling with the basic problem of getting autocomplete to work.

Comment: Thanks - helped me to find the problem I was having, which was with the data format - according to [the docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#overview), you can use an array of objects with object and value properties, like this:

`[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

but for some reason it didn't like this, until I added quotes around the _label_ and _value_ labels:

`[ { "label": "Choice1", "value": "value1" }, ... ]`

Then it worked nicely - hope this helps someone else too!

Answer (score 2):

Just like I answered **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700371/not-sure-how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete/3700574)**, take a loot at my working example of jQuery UI's autocomplete. Pay attention to the `source` part. Hope it helps:

```
    var cache = {};
    $("#textbox").autocomplete({
      source: function(request, response) {
       if (request.term in cache) {
        response($.map(cache[request.term].d, function(item) {
         return { value: item.value, id: item.id }
        }))
        return;
       }
       $.ajax({
        url: "/Services/AutoCompleteService.asmx/GetEmployees",  /* I use a web service */
        data: "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "' }",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataFilter: function(data) { return data; },
        success: function(data) {
         cache[request.term] = data;
         response($.map(data.d, function(item) {
          return {
           value: item.value,
           id: item.id
          }
         }))
        },
        error: HandleAjaxError  // custom method
       });
      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function(event, ui) {
       if (ui.item) {
        formatAutoComplete(ui.item);   // custom method
       }
      }
     });
```

If you're not doing so by now, get **[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)**. It's an invaluable tool for web development. You can set a breakpoint on this JavaScript and see what happens.

Comment: @Rafael: I had a deep looking to your sample and it seems to me almost identical. I dont need to pass "data.d" to the map function. Anyway as I wrote on my question if I write "alert(item.text)" as the first istruction inside the map function I can see the correct data showing up.

Comment: @Lorenzo: try parsing the "source" as shown in my example. The previous person I helped (and myself) had problems unless we parsed it with $.map.

Comment: @Rafael: What do you mean by parsing with map? For me, it seems that I am using the map function exactly as your sample. Could you please explain more? thank you

Comment: @Lorenzo: you're right, yours is pretty identical to mine. Could you please try two things: adding the dataFilter and contentType properties to your $.ajax from my code. It's the only differences I can spot (besides your data: {} not being sent json parsed, like  "{ 'term': '" + request.term + "' }").

Comment: @Rafael: I dont think that the problem is related to sending or receiving data. The problem is encountered inside the _create function of the Autocomplete plugin. In particular when it creates the UL that will contains the items in the istruction ".zIndex( this.element.zIndex() + 1 )".

Answer (score 1):

fgmenu Using the function menu() AND autocomplete Using the function

The function name is the same problems occur

You can change the function name in the fgmenu.js

```
  $('#hierarchybreadcrumb6').menuA({content: $('#hierarchybreadcrumb6').next().html(),backLink: false});
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Lorenzo answer i modified

```
$.fn.fgmenu = function(options) { ...
```

to

```
$.fn.fgmenu = function(options) { ...
```

from this plugins [menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_and_flyout_menus/) and it worked fine (both autocomplete and menu plugin)