# jquery ui autocomplete - how to?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I may be looking at this all wrong.

But, I am trying to use the jquery ui autocomplete.

I want to pass it a url and it will get the suggestions from there.

my questions are
1: how do i specify the url?
2: how do i format the response?

Comment: here is a fully functioning example right here in stackoverflow  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700371/not-sure-how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete

Comment: This doesn't help? - http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Comment: ah much better. i was looking here: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should get you started with specifying the URL part.

First create an input field to attach the autocomplete plugin to.

```
<input type="text" name="query" />
```

Then use this javascript to attach the autocomplete to the input box just created.

```
   $("#query").autocomplete({
       source: "/suggestions/get/",
       select: function(event, ui) {
          $("#new-field").val(ui.item.value);
       }
    });
```

The request uri will be something like this...

```
/suggestions/get/?term={selection}
```

`selection` represents the selection made in autocomplete.

Now on your server side you need to parse the uri and use the value of parameter `term` to do whatever you want - search the database for the selected choice, or something else.

You should format your response like this...

```
suggestion1
suggestion2
suggestion3
suggestion4
```

The suggestions should be on a new line (separated by `\n`)

Comment: Yes, but what does the server-side response look like?--this seems to be undocumented and unexampled.

Answer (score 1):

On the jquery UI page you have a complete demo with different examples, that should be enough I think. [Here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)'s the url.

Comment: -1 this is a comment. If this is an answer, it would have address the question of the OP.

Comment: @Reigel: examples on that page are quite simple and they address the user problems. Not sure why you think that this should be a comment. The user didn't know about this url and (according his latest comment) IS useful for him.

Comment: @Claudio - I got this comment (and a downvote for good measure) from a moderator of SO sometime back for an answer of mine. `The identification of duplicates/answering the question with other URLs should be done with a comment.`

Comment: @ShiVik: Seems that the moderator meant that you should not answer with a link to another question on SO. This is not the same case :) (I'm pasting an external link)

Comment: @Claudio - I think the comment was meant for other urls as well. If I understand it correctly, questions on SO are not only meant to solve the problem for the user who asked the question but also for other users who are having the same problem. For them it is an archive of Q&A. But if the URL you supplied in your answer goes dead that would mean the question, effectively, has no answer.

Comment: I'm not linking to a random link I found on google I'm linking to the official documentation. Anyway, I get your point. Thanks man.

Comment: @ShiVik: +1 for you too. Your point is valid too and your answer is good :)