# jquery ui autocomplete bugs - i can't make it work with json

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

By following the example of [binaryhowl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700371/not-sure-how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete/3700574) I've tried to make my autocomplete dynamic.

Source is [here](http://pastebin.com/h8hRYFY9) which should be of close resemblance (modified to fit the url I retrieve my info from).

lookup.php returns json compliant (UTF8) results as per (plaintext):

```
["value1","value2","value3","value4","value5"]
```

If I provide a hardcoded version of the url for source:

```
source: "lookup.php?type=some_case&value=search_term"
```

The autocomplete list of suggestions is piled up as expected.

Lookup.php supports

```
application/json; charset=utf-8
```

And I get the following bugs from jquery:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'menu' jquery-1.5.1.js:869
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of undefined jquery.ui.autocomplete.js:337
>   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of null  jquery-1.5.1.js:869

As seen here:

[image]

All js scripts are directly from [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/jquery-1.5.1.js) and [here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.autocomplete.js), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend against picking and choosing jQueryUI components from the github repository you linked to. This error, for example:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object
>   Object] has no method 'menu'
>   jquery-1.5.1.js:869 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property
>   'element' of undefined
>   jquery.ui.autocomplete.js:337 Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'd' of
>   null jquery-1.5.1.js:869

Is because the autocomplete widget is trying to use the `menu` widget (an internal widget that is used by autocomplete).

I would recommend downloading the widgets you need using [jQueryUI's download page](http://jqueryui.com/download), which will download the necessary files for the widgets you choose, or if you're using most of them, use [jQueryUI hosted on a CDN](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/CDNjQueryUI1812.ashx).

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but sadly I tried that already (created a custom with only those needed for autocomplete, and tried your link just now)

Comment: @Josh: Did you try linking to the CDN? The error containing the language about the `menu` tells me something is missing.

Comment: @Andrew: thanks. I've done so and now I get the following: **Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete'** but the js for autocomplete should be included.

Comment: @Andrew: it was a js ref problem. But for good practice I'll add that my json reply wasn't properly json (i lacked var names which turned out to cause additional problems). Thanks! :)

Comment: @Josh: Okay, glad you figured it out!

Comment: make sure you're using the lastest version of jquery. i ran into the exact same problem not to long ago and got really frustrated... only to find out that the version of jquery that i was using wasn't up to date.