# jquery autocomplete not picking up array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am building a website. On the website I have a search form that should use autocomplete to find data in the database. The backend part is ready but the fron-end part I can not get it to work. I found this post: [Is it possible to change the Url which JQuery's JQueryUI Autocomplete generates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694551/is-it-possible-to-change-the-url-which-jquerys-jqueryui-autocomplete-generates) but it looks like the response is not used in the searchbar.

I have my webpage running only locally so I can not show it, but the code I have (left some parts such as doctype and head out for easy reading):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="country-by-name">Country: </label>
    <input id="country-by-name">
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#country-by-name").autocomplete({
    source: function(req, resp){
                $.get('/data/country/by-name/'+ encodeURIComponent(req.term), function(json){
                    var numCountries = json['countries'].length;
                    if(numCountries > 0){
                        var countryNames = [];
                        for(var i = 0; i < numCountries; i++){
                            countryNames.push(json['countries'][i]['name']);
                        }
                        resp = countryNames;
                        console.log(resp);
                    }else{
                        resp = [];
                    }
                    return resp;
                });
            },
    minLength: 2
});
</script>
```

The backend works fine, if I for example go to: /data/country/by-name/zi then it retuns json:

```
{"countries": [{"id": 812, "name": "Brazil"}, {"id": 995, "name": "Swaziland"}, {"id": 1033, "name": "Zimbabwe"}]}
```

This is also picked up by javascript because if I console.log() it shows up:

```
(3) ["Brazil", "Swaziland", "Zimbabwe"]
```

So the data is there, but not picked up by the automcomplete function of jquery. Does anyone have an idea why "resp" is not used for autocomplete?

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I didn't realize that "resp" is a callback function. So I should have used resp(countryNames)